# Angular mat-select text color doesn't change

Tags: css, angular, material-design

I am using mat-select in my Angular application. I would like to change the text color, but the color doesn't change.

```
<mat-select style="color: red" [(ngModel)]="someValue">
  <mat-option>class="empty-select"</mat-option>
  <mat-option class="not-empty-select" *ngFor="let unit of units [value]="unit">{{unit}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I can change the background color without problems, but the text color doesn't change.

Answer (score 21):

You need to apply style on `mat-option` rather than `mat-select` as:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="someValue">
  <mat-option class="empty-select"></mat-option>
  <mat-option style="color: red" class="not-empty-select" *ngFor="let unit of units [value]="unit">{{unit}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Also you can set color in class `not-empty-select`.

**Update 1:**

If you want to change color of selected option add following CSS:

```
.not-empty-select.mat-selected {
  color: green !important;
}
```

**Update 2:**

If you want to change color in select box modify CSS as:

```
.not-empty-select.mat-selected {
  color: green !important;
}

:host /deep/ .mat-select-value-text {
  color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: This work on the options, but not on the selected value. I want the color red to appear on the selected value.

Comment: Hi Anshuman. That works when you open the select, but not when you do not open the select. I want to see the green color when the screen is loaded and I do not click on the select yet. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Hi @AnshumanJaiswal is there a way to apply the :host /deep/ within the custom class so as not to affect all select texts on the page?

Comment: Use <mat-select-trigger class="mynewcolor">{{ selectedvalue }}</mat-select-trigger> for changing the view before clicked (the trigger).

Answer (score 18):

If you check closely mat-select-value is the class which holds the css for placeholer font in mat-select tag;

so Using

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-value{    
      color: white!important;  }
```

will apply the color you give. !important is to override the default value.

Comment: Adding :host in the beginning of the style will make it limited to the scope of component instead of leaking to global styles.

Answer (score 11):

You can overwrite the css for following elements as -

## Select box panel

```
/deep/ .mat-select-panel {
    background-color: red;
}
```

## Select box options element

```
/deep/ .mat-form-field-infix{
     background-color: red;
}
```

## Select box

```
/deep/ .mat-select{
   background-color: red;
}
```

> do not forget to add /deep/ as mentioned.

### Select Box text color

Use this one if you want to change the text color of select.

```
/deep/ .mat-form-field-type-mat-select .mat-form-field-label, .mat-select-value {
  color: red;
}
```

Demo copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-pagination-123456-5teixy

Comment: Hi Sunil, thanks for your reply. The 3rd option is exactly what I am looking for, but unfortunately this doesn't work for the text color. Nothing changes if I do this:
/deep/ .mat-select{
   color: red;
}

Comment: Added the css overriding for text color `Select Box text color`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your styles.css file

```
.mat-select-red .mat-select-value{
   color: red !important;
}
```

In your component.html file

```
<mat-select class="mat-select-red" [(ngModel)]="someValue">
  <mat-option>class="empty-select"</mat-option>
  <mat-option class="not-empty-select" *ngFor="let unit of units [value]="unit">{{unit}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: This will change the style for entire application.

Comment: The you will have define the classed using ::ng-deep on that particular component.css file.

Answer (score 1):

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
  display: none !important;
}
```

its works for me

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answers already provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <mat-select  [(ngModel)]="someValue">
      <mat-option style="color: red" >class="empty-select"</mat-option>
      <mat-option style="color: red" class="not-empty-select" 
         *ngFor="let unit of units [value]="unit">{{unit}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
option appearance (legacy, standard, fill, outline)

<mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
   <mat-label>Choose an option</mat-label>
   <mat-select>
      <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>...
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You should probably add a little more context to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have this select:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>The label</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
        <mat-option value="This">This</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="That">That</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is displayed like this:

[image]

To style the colors only, try this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple {
    background-color: red;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
    color: red;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused.mat-primary .mat-select-arrow{
    color: red;
}

::ng-deep .mat-primary .mat-option.mat-selected:not(.mat-option-disabled){
    color: red;
}
```

Which produces

[image]

This works on Angular 11.2.0, Angular Material 11.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me change the style of the selected text:

`::ng-deep .mat-selected .mat-option-text { color: white!important; }`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you need to set the color of mat-option from a variable you should:

1. Set panelClass in mat-select:

   <mat-select **panelClass="inherit-color"**>
2. Set css rule:

   .inherit-color .mat-option {
   **color: inherit!important;**
   }
3. Wrap mat-option in span and set the style in it:

   ```
       <span style="color: {{somevar}}">
         <mat-option [value]="someval">{{someval}}</mat-option> 
       </span>
   ```