# Angular 7 - Change color of Mat-select-value based on condition

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a mat select and I would like to change the color of the selected value based on a condition. basically to show the user that a change was made. I know that I can access the `mat-select-value` from the styles but not sure how to implement a condition to it using ng-class:

```
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select name="list"  
      [style.color]="myCondtition ? 'none': 'green'"
      (selectionChange)="change()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="currentOption">
          {{option.viewvalue}}
         </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
```

I was able to get things like `[style.font-weight]`, `[style.background-color]` and `[style.font-size`] to work but there is no `font-color` and just [style.color]only seems to work with inputs.

Comment: I think you can find useful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813506/angular-mat-select-text-color-doesnt-change/52813599)

Comment: @SillyCoon I checked there but that only worked on the option list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the normal class property with the condition

```
<mat-select class="{{myCondition ? 'one' : 'two'}}" > ... </mat-select>
```

and give the style to the corresponding class

```
::ng-deep {
    .two .mat-select-value-text {
      color : red;
     }
     .one .mat-select-value-text {
      color : green;
     }
   }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-6rylbe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Works NIcely! I was able to put the style in the global style sheet and avoid using ::ng-deep