# Adding Custom Scss into ng-select (change dropdownlist text color)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I tried change text color of dropdown list. It didnot workour. Please help me out,. I am using angular version 12.
This is my component template

```
<ng-select [items]="dropdownList" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"  class="custom"
          (change)="updateObj($event)">
        </ng-select>
```

Anyhelp Appreciable,..

Answer (score 0):

Add selector for your `custom` class in `.css` file of that component with `!important` flag. (green as example)

`.custom { color: green !important; }`

Useful link (potential duplicate) --> [Angular mat-select text color doesn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813506/angular-mat-select-text-color-doesnt-change)

Comment: thank you so much. but it did not workout for dropdown list.

Comment: I want to add custom style for following tag,
ng-select, .ng-select div, .ng-select input, .ng-select span{
color:blue;
} , My every attempt was defeated ,......